# How do I view multiple Excel files in a single workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

How do I view multiple separate Excel files in a single workbook?

Right now I have 6 worksheets open in Excel 2013 and it is saturated with tool bars.

If I hide the tool bars then when I format I have to open each toolbar.

Comment: You can open multiple workbooks with one instance of Excel and then use them one at a time.  Are you talking about having them all visible simultaneously, like tiled, but without the overhead of duplicate tool bars?. Are you looking to permanently merge them into one workbook or just temporarily access them all?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to consolidate every file into one but i will suggest you these methods :

1. **If you have time :** Copy paste the data or import the data to main
   excel sheet. Steps for connecting are given here -   https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-data-in-another-workbook-to-your-workbook-3a557ddb-70f3-400b-b48c-0c86ce62b4f5
2. **If you don't have time :** There is a tool which can either be
   purchased or use as a trial version. The tool simply gives you the
   option to merge the excel sheet.You can get it here -
   https://www.ablebits.com/consolidate-worksheets-excel/worksheets-consolidation.php
3. **If you are a programmer :** Use VB to merge the files - by doing the steps given here - http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/456-combine-multiple-workbooks.html

Comment: You cover a lot of territory in your answer, which is great.  However, the meat of each piece is in a link.  If the links break or are unavailable, what's left would be just a hint.  The answer would be much better if you include the essential information here and use the links just for attribution and further reading.

Comment: Essentially I want one worksheet with one toolbar. I do not want to merge data as my 6 worksheets are linked, if I have more of my product I just load in another worksheet and in some cases I will have over 10 worksheets loaded & all linked. In Excel 2013 my monitor is now filled up with 25% ++ of toolbars when I open my 6 worksheets. Instead of going to one toolbar for formatting I know have to unhide and view one for each worksheet. Can Excel 2013 use the 2010 format for worksheets?

Comment: are the sheets being shared with others, this might be the reason why the toolbars are having different settings. And yes you can use 2010 format with 2013

Comment: The sheets are not shared with others, how do I have 6 worksheets loaded with only one toolbar (not 6 toolbars) without using the hide toolbar option?